# Help with interpreting the regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

This is the first time I'm using regression analysis and I'm not sure what I need to write for my interpretation that would make sense.

I'm trying to write about the impact of oil price changes on the stock market. I've used the daily data for the last 15 years.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It is a good idea to start with writing down the regression equation something like $y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 * x_t + \epsilon_t$ and then explain in your question what the dependent variable measures and what the independent variables measures. Remember to specify the units. This is essential to get anywhere with respect to interpreting the coefficients.

Comment: Please add self-study tag. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#10812 and edit your question to show your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R square  is called the coefficient of determination. It is the degree to which the model predicts the dependent variable with the given independent variables. In short, R is calculated as the correlation between the actual dependent variable and the predicted dependent variable using this regression model. The adjusted R square is the adjustment made into R square for the number of predictor variables.

The R Square value closer to 1 denotes the model is able to predict the dependent variables much closer to the actual and model is fit. Here, R Square value is almost zero, which means that your model will be of much use for prediction.

The ANOVA tests the assumptions the the coefficient of the predictor is equal to zero. The regression sum of squares is the total variance in the dependent variable explained by the regression model. The Residual sum of squares is the total variance in the dependent variable that is unexplained by the regression model. The mean sum of squares are the sum of squares of each divided by their corresponding degrees of freedom.

Assuming your model has high R square (not TRUE in this case)

The intercept is the value of % Change in Daily StockMarket Index, when the change in WTI Close Price is zero. Here, it is 0.03161. The coeffient of WTI Close Price Daily % change denotes the amount of % change in Daily StockMarket Index, when the % change in WTI Close Price is 1.

You can frame the regression equation as

**StockMarket Daily % Change = 0.03161 + (0.06857*WTI Close Price Daily % change)**

Even though, significance of the intercept is greater than 0.05, it is important to have the intercept in the model.